# How to can change my template in blogger?

Tags: blogger

How can I change it ? I don't like the default blogger templates and I have downloaded a new template , but I don't know how to put it

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)", "[mcve]" and their linked pages. Your question isn't asked well as you don't show any attempt toward solving the problem.

Answer (score -1):

- enter appearance
- click allocation button
- enter edit html
- copy your html template file that your like then paste it (Note : you must remove the previous template code before pasting )

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and its linked pages. Your answer doesn't have enough detail to help anyone who is searching for a solution.